# I'm setting up java on vs code and (1) problem keeps popping up even if the code is running and a small line below the p in public class

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpxBg.png)

I cant figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hover over it and check the warning message. You are missing the package name I suppose and welcome to Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment under the issue [Warning: Classpath is incomplete. Only syntax errors will be reported.](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/107) gave the explanation:

> This warning is displayed when you open a single java file, because at
> that point, no classpath can be configured thus no information on
> types other than the default JDK can be provided. In that case, only
> syntax errors are reported.

Open Command Palette and choose **Java: Create Java Project**, then code in your new project, there won't be this kind of errors.

Comment: @AhmedMahmoud. Please [accept and upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67806353/module-pyautogui-is-not-importing-correctly-despite-installing-successfully-in) my answer if it solves your question. Don't hesitate to let me know if you have any other problems.